# How to indent paragraphs in an adapted enumeration?

Tags: indentation

I'm writing a document with solutions for exercises. In the case of subquestions, I'm using an enumeration. Since a subanswer can be quite long, I don't want the items to be indented and I'd like to start the second line underneath the enumeration label.

For the moment, I'm using `wide=0pt` for this, but that also kills the paragraph indentation. Using `\setlist{listparindent=\parindent}` doesn't work. How can I restore the spacing before *Part x.* in the example underneath?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item\relax
    {\bfseries
        #1\@addpunct{.}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\setlist{  
    listparindent=\parindent,
    parsep=0pt
}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}[(a), wide=0pt]
        \item \textit{Part 1.} \lipsum[66]      
        \textit{Part 2.} \lipsum[66]    
        \textit{Part 3.} \lipsum[66]
        \item   \lipsum[66]
        \item \lipsum[66]\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item\relax
    {\bfseries
        #1\@addpunct{.}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\setlist{
    listparindent=\parindent,
    parsep=0pt
}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}[label =(a), wide,labelindent=0pt]
        \item \textit{Part 1.} \lipsum[66]
        \textit{Part 2.} \lipsum[66]
        \textit{Part 3.} \lipsum[66]
        \item \lipsum[66]
        \item \lipsum[66]\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect Bernard! :)